Boosting a field in an OpenSearch Python query without ^
Is there a way to boost a field in an OpenSearch Python query without using ^ directly on the field name?
I have the following query (just part of it) –and it works– but I want something more readable:
    "multi_match": {
        "query": _search_terms,
        "fields": [ 
            "foo^1.5", # 1.5x boost
            "bar^1.3", # 1.3x boost
            "lorem", # no boost
        ],
        "type": "most_fields",
    }

I was giving Chat GPT a shot and it told me I could do:
    "fields": [
        { "foo": { "boost": 1.5 } },
        { "bar": { "boost": 1.3 } },
        "XYZ"
    ]

But I get:
"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:133] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"

